Conda Install PyTorch Results in Incorrect Version
I'm trying to install PyTorch through Conda. However, when I run the following command according to the PyTorch documentation:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia

it does not seem to install the correct pytorch-cuda version. That is, running
>>> torch.version.cuda
'12.1'

This is a problem because then when I run
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
UserWarning: CUDA initialization: The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 11020). Please update your GPU driver by downloading and installing a new version from the URL: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install a PyTorch version that has been compiled with your version of the CUDA driver. (Triggered internally at ../c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:108.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0

How do I fix this?
I tried rearranging the order of the packages. I also tried changing the version of Python from 3.8.19 -> 3.8.18.

Can you get the output of nvidia-smi?

Have you checked if you are actually importing from the currently active env? Maybe you are importing a version different from the one you installed
